# How do I move an Amazon micro instance to a small instance?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I want to move my instance to a micro instance to a small instance but when I try to launch a new AMI based on my Micro instance AMI it only gives me the option for 64 bit instances.

My initial ami is based off an ubuntu 10.04 image.

Is it not possible to move between 64 bit and 32 bit instance?

Comment: your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks I asked there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 64-bit image requires a 64-bit instance. 32-bit for 32-bit. You can have a 64-bit Micro instance, <strike>but I believe that Small instances are only available in the 32-bit flavor</strike>.

- **Update**: AWS has meanwhile introduced *64-bit Ubiquity*, i.e. every instance type can be used with 64-bit images, which indeed *will make it easier for you to scale vertically (to larger and smaller instances) without having to maintain parallel (32 and 64-bit) AMIs* (see [EC2 Updates: New Medium Instance, 64-bit Ubiquity, SSH Client](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/ec2-updates-new-instance-64-bit-bit-ubiquity-ssh-client.html) for details).